# Prove that $P(X(n) ≤ k\ln(n)) = 0$ for $k < 1$ and that $P(X(n) ≤ k\ln(n)) = 1$ for $k > 1$

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be a collection of independent exponentially distributed random variables each with rate parameter equal to $1$ ($ = 1$).

Also for each integer $n ≥ 1$, let $X_{(n)}$ = $\max\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}$.

Show that for $k < 1$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_{(n)}≤k\ln(n)) = 0$$

Also show that for $k > 1$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_{(n)}≤k\ln(n)) = 1$$

I know how to figure out the CDF of the $X_{(n)}$ , which is (with $ = 1$)
$$F_{X_{(n)}} = P(X_{(n)}≤x) = [1-e^{-x}]^n$$

But I got stuck here. I am not sure how to proceed to show the two separate limit values.

Help is much appreciated. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So taking $x=k\ln(n)$, you have, for any $k>0$,
$$P\Bigl(X_{(n)}\le k\ln(n)\Bigr)=\left(1-\mathrm e^{-k\ln(n)}\right)^{\!n}=
\exp\left(n\ln\Bigl(1-n^{-k}\Bigr)\right).$$
Since $\ln(1-n^{-k})\sim-n^{-k}$ as $n\to\infty$, the last expression is $\exp\bigl(-n^{1-k}+o(n^{1-k})\bigr)$. Can you conclude?

Comment: Sorry, but I am having trouble understanding. I understand how you got up to exp(nln(1-n^-k)), but I don't really understand how you went from that to the last expression is exp(-n^(1-k) + o(n^(1-k)). Would you please expand a bit more? Thank you.

Comment: @passerby I updated my answer. Basically, $\ln(1+x)\approx x$ for $x$ small (the logarithm of $1+x$ at $0$ is best approximated by its tangent).

Comment: If you want, you can form $$n\ln\Bigl(1-n^{-k}\Bigr)=\frac{\ln\Bigl(1-n^{-k}\Bigr)}{n^{-k}}\cdot n^{1-k}$$ and use that $$\frac{\ln\Bigl(1-n^{-k}\Bigr)}{n^{-k}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}-\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\Bigl[\ln(1-x)\Bigr]\Big|_{x=0}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your expansion. I understand it a bit better now and get the -n^(1-k) portion, but what is that o(n^(1-k))? I don't understand that notation and/or why it is there. I am sorry for troubling you. If you could let me know what that topic/technique is I can also look it up. Furthermore, for your second comment with the d/dx, is that just l'hospital?

Comment: It's [little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation). But you can forget about that and check my other comment.

Comment: I am not really following the second line of the second comment and I am not sure how to proceed unfortunately.

Comment: @passerby it's $(f(x)-f(0))/(x-0)$ for $f(x)=\ln(1-x)$ and $x=n^{-k}\to0$, so it tends to $f'(0)$. However I put a minus sign which shouldn't be there, sorry.